# AngularJS How to use RESTful with factory module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory, angular-resource

I have been getting an error to make RESTful code for 2 hours.

I have one file has a controller here

```
angular.module('orderToBeShippedApp',['ng','projectService'])

    .controller('orderCtrl',function($scope, Project){

        Project.query(function(data){
            alert(data);
            $scope.projects = data;
        });

    });
```

Here is my fatory which is called 'project'.

```
angular.module('projectService',['ng','ngResource'])
   .factory('Project',function($resource){

      return $resource('api/url/:projectId.json',{},{
        query:{
          method:'get',
          params: {projectId:"test"},
          isArray: false
        }
      });

   });
```

My html:

```
<div ng-controller = "orderCtrl" class ="col-sm-8 col-md-9">
    <!--Body content -->
    <div  ng-repeat = "project in projects">
        <h2>{{project.name}}</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

My json is something like

```
[
    {
    "age": 0, 
    "id": "a", 
    "imageUrl": "a0.jpg", 
    "name": "b", 
    "snippet": "Tbaa."
   }, 
 {
    "age": 1, 
    "id": "mo", 
    "imageUrl": "assets/images/phones/mo.0.jpg", 
    "name": "M\u2122", 
    "snippet": "The Ned by Android 3.0 (Honeycomb)."
  }

]
```

It doesn't give me any error message on the browser. it seems having a problem on factory function.

Could anyone help me to fix it?

Comment: in the network tab of chrome what is the url it is trying to hit?

Comment: On chrome, I got XMLHttpRequest cannot load error. so I switched to firefox. and I don't get any urls on network.

Comment: I have updated my answer to get you over this xmlHttpRequest error. This might be the main issue

Comment: Try to run server, what kind of error you have – please share more details. Change name method to **GET**

Answer (score 0):

You should change your binding to be `name`, not `ProjectName` based on your model definition:

```
<div ng-controller = "orderCtrl" class ="col-sm-8 col-md-9">
<!--Body content -->
<div  ng-repeat = "project in projects">
    <h2>{{project.name}}</h2>
</div>
```

Also, to use `ngResource` you need to remember to add a script reference to: `angular-resource`:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE:**

1. Remove 'ng' Dependency
2. Pass the resource to the controller as a dependency.

   ```
   // resource
   angular.module('projectService',['ngResource'])
   .factory('Project',function($resource){
       return $resource('api/url/:projectId.json',{},{
           query:{
             method:'get',
             params: {projectId:"test"},
             isArray: false
           }
       });
   });
   // controller
   angular.module('orderToBeShippedApp',['projectService'])
   .controller('orderCtrl',['$scope','Project', function($scope, Project){
       Project.query(function(data){
           alert(data);
           $scope.projects = data;
       });
   }]);
   ```

Comment: Well sorry, there was my mistake when I make the code simpler. Cuz my original code needs project.ProjectName. But my problem is I can't even query the project. it is empty.

Comment: I also add angular-resource. I don't get any error message. Doesn't have problem with 'project' factory module.

Comment: The problem hasn't been fixed yet. projectName was my mistake not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your factory may not be giving a console error however it may not be able to bring back the data. Your factory should be looking like this:

```
angular.module('projectService',['ng','ngResource'])
  .factory('Project',function($resource){

  return {
    projects: $resource('api/url/:projectId.json', {projectId: '@test'})
    }
  });
}]);
```

In your controller it should invoke the method like this:

```
angular.module('orderToBeShippedApp',['ng','projectService'])

.controller('orderCtrl',['$scope','Project',function($scope, Project){

     $scope.projects = Project.projects.get({id: 'test'});

}]);
```

UPDATE:

In order to relax chrome the xmlHttpRequest error you need to run this command from the chrome.exe folder of your machine:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security
```